# Popup window on landing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I made a landing page with goods.
Every good has a description and a price.
When you click open a "popup window" should open, with the picture and description.
The question is, what if i have a lot of goods so with html and some framework popup, I will need to do all the description in html, can I somehow make a template of popup window, and provide description of goods in popup window through javascript ?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can do this and we look forward to helping you with your code when you are stuck.  Please post your code when you get that far and are stuck at a specific part of the code.

Comment: @DanAndrews, thank for you answer, the problem is, I dont where to start, should look for some framework ?

Comment: You have a serious problem that deserves a good answer.  Unfortunately, stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask questions like this.  Doing more research (such as frameworks) would definitely help you - you need to do this, we can't do it for you.

Comment: There are lots and lots of javascript modal/dialog scripts/plugins available all over the web

Comment: I believe you're looking for something like a partial file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need a code which displays a modal window and the same code should also display full product details in it.

Normally, if you have a category page which displays product summary you would need to populate the modal window (which some call popup) with complete product details taken in via Ajax (the website should be able to output product data in JSON format if you got to an URL like mystore.com/ajax/p/10101 where 10101 is the product id. It depends on the website creator.

Anyways, an example JS code with modal window and which displays the product info from the page you are on is below.

```js
$(".view").click(function(){
  
  $(".overlay").show();
  
  var pName = $(this).parent().children(".itemName").text();
  var pPrice = $(this).parent().children(".itemPrice").text();
  var pDescription = $(this).parent().children(".itemDescription").text();
  
  $(".productName").text(pName);
  $(".productPrice").text(pPrice);
  $(".productDescription").text(pDescription);
  
  
  });


$(".close").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  
  $(".overlay").hide();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  }

.products {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  
  }

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
 }

.itemImage {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 138px;
  border: solid 1px green;
  margin-right: 10px;
  }

.itemName {
  font: 500 20px/25px Arial;
  
  }

.itemPrice {
  font-weight: bolder;
  }

.itemDescription {
  font: 300 16px/18px Arial;
  
  }

.view {
font: 100 9px/10px Arial;
}

.view:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}



.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

  }

.popup {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  }
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  }

.product {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  }



.productImage {
  width: 100px;;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  }

.productName {
font: 500 15px/16px Arial;  
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  
<div class="products">
  
  
  <div class="item">  
    <div class="itemImage"><img src="" /></div>

    <div class="itemName"> Product 1</div>    
    <div class="itemPrice"> $100 </div>
    <div class="itemDescription"> Description 1 in here.</div>  
    <span class="view">View popup</span>
  </div>

    <div class="item">  
    <div class="itemImage"><img src="" /></div>

    <div class="itemName"> Product 2</div>    
    <div class="itemPrice"> $300 </div>
    <div class="itemDescription"> Description 2 in here.</div>  
      <span class="view">View popup</span>
  </div>
  

  
  </div>

<div class="overlay">
 
    <div class="popup">
      <a href="#" class="close">Close X</a>
      
      <div class="product">  
        <div class="productImage"><img src="" /></div>

        <div class="productName"> xxxxxx</div>    
        <div class="productPrice"> uuuuuuuu </div>
        <div class="productDescription"> tttttttt </div>  
      </div>
      
    </div>
  
 </div>
  
  </div>
```